# Canvas crispy text rendering

Tags: html, node.js, canvas, bitmap, electron

i am using electron(nodejs framework ) and i want to render crispy text for convert it into bitmap and show it on led brick.
like led show software please help.

my code is working but it's system dependent it working fine in some computer but to blurry in some computer.

calling parameter in main.js.

```
let height = 96;
let width = 288;
let letterSpacing = 1;
var font = "Arial";
var fontSize = 11;
let text_x = 1;
let text_y = 1;
const canvas = new Canvas(height, width, letterSpacing, font, fontSize, text_x, text_y);
```

here is my canvas.js file.

```
class Canvas {
constructor(height, width, latterSpacing = 1, font, fontSize, text_x, text_y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.letterSpacing = latterSpacing;
    this.font = font;
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
    this.text_x = text_x;
    this.text_y = text_y;

    this.maxWidth = 32;
    this.offset = 0.5;

    this.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
}

PIXEL_RATIO = (function () {
    // var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d"),
        // var ctx = this.ctx,
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

    return dpr / bsr;
})();

setwidth(maxwidth) {
    this.maxWidth = maxwidth;
    // this.offset = ofset;
}

setoffset(ofset) {
    // this.maxWidth = maxwidth;
    this.offset = ofset;
}

createHiDPICanvas = function (w, h, ratio) {
    if (!ratio) { ratio = this.PIXEL_RATIO; }
    // var can = document.createElement("canvas");
    var can = this.canvas;
    can.width = w * ratio;
    can.height = h * ratio;
    can.style.width = w + "px";
    can.style.height = h + "px";
    can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
    return can;
}

createCanvas() {
    try {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        this.canvas.retinaResolutionEnabled = false;
        // this.canvas.style.letterSpacing = "1px";
        this.canvas.height = this.height;
        this.canvas.width = this.width;

        this.canvas.style.letterSpacing = `${this.letterSpacing}px`                                    
        /*word spacing*/

        // var can = this.createHiDPICanvas(this.width, this.height, 4)
        // this.ctx = can.getContext("2d")

        this.ctx.beginPath();
        // this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        this.ctx.font = `${this.fontSize}px ` + this.font;                                            
        /*Font style and size*/
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
        this.ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        this.ctx.textAlign = 'start';
        this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;

        this.canvas.retinaResolutionEnabled = false;

        // this.ctx.fillText("WELCOME TO TICO", 10, 20);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

clrCanvas(ix = 0, iy = 0, ex = this.canvas.width, ey = this.canvas.height) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(ix, iy, ex, ey);
}

fillTextCanvas(str, row = 0, col = 0, vac = 0, hac = 1, _fontSize = this.fontSize, _font = this.font) 
{

    this.ctx.font = `${_fontSize}px ` + _font;

    if (vac) {
        col = ((this.canvas.height - (str.length * _fontSize)) / 2) + 1;
    }

    if (hac) {
        this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        row = this.width / 2;
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
        // const element = array[index];
        let y = (_fontSize * index) + col;
        // this.ctx.fillText(str[index], width / 2, y);                                             
        /*text,x,y*/
        this.ctx.fillText(str[index], row - 0.8, y - 0.8);                                             
         /*text,x,y*/
        // this.ctx.fillText("hello", width/2, y);                                             
        /*text,x,y*/
    }

    // display_hex["Screen2"] = jsonArr;
    // fillMatrix(jsonArr);
}

async getBitmap() {
    var jsonArr = {};
    var bin = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < this.canvas.width; j++) {
        bin = ""
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.canvas.height; i++) {
            var data = this.ctx.getImageData(j, i, 1, 1);                         /*getPixel,x,y*/

            if (!(i % 32) && i) {
                // jsonArr[j + (width * (Math.floor(i / 32) - 1))] = ("0x" + (("00000000" + 
             ConvertBase.bin2hex(bin)).substr(-8)));
                jsonArr[j + (this.width * (Math.floor(i / 32) - 1))] = 
                parseInt(ConvertBase.bin2dec(bin));
                bin = "";
            }

            if (data['data'][0] >= 200 && data['data'][3] >= 90) {
                bin += "1";
            } else {
                bin += "0";
            }
        }
    }

    return jsonArr;
}

fillCanvas(_char, row, col, _fontSize = 11, _font = "Arial") {
    this.clrCanvas();
    this.ctx.font = `${_fontSize}px ` + _font;
    this.ctx.textAlign = "start";
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    // let linesPos = [[0, 45, 80, 119, 157, 196, 235], [1, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84]]
    // let linesPos = [[0, 49, 81, 119, 157, 196, 235], [1, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]]
    let linesPos = [[0, 60, 98, 135, 174, 213, 252], [1, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78]]

    this.findColPos(_char);

    // console.log(_char)

    for (let _row = row; _row < _char.length; _row++) {
        // let y = parseInt(text_y) + ((parseInt(fontSize) + 2) * _row);
        let y = parseInt(this.text_y + 1) + ((parseInt(_fontSize)) * _row);

        for (let index = col; index < _char[_row].length; index++) {
            let x = parseInt(this.text_x) + linesPos[0][index];

            console.log(this.ctx.measureText(_char[_row][index]).width)
            // this.ctx.fillText(_char[_row][index], x + 1.8, y + 0.8,32);                                             
            /*text,x,y*/
            this.ctx.fillText(_char[_row][index], x + this.offset, y + this.offset, this.maxWidth);                                             
            /*text,x,y*/

            this.ctx.moveTo(0, linesPos[1][index + 1] + 0.5);
            this.ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width, linesPos[1][index + 1] + 0.5);

            this.ctx.moveTo(linesPos[0][index] + 0.5, 0);
            this.ctx.lineTo(linesPos[0][index] + 0.5, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // display_hex["Screen1"] = jsonArr;

    // canvasImg["Screen1"] = ($('#myCanvas')[0]).toDataURL("image/png");
    // fillMatrix(jsonArr);
    // return jsonArr;
}

findColPos(__char) {
    let maxRow = []
    maxRow[0] = 0;
    let splitData = [];

    maxRow[0] = [];
    maxRow[1] = [];
    for (let pos = 0; pos < __char[0].length; pos++) {
        if (__char[0][pos].split(" ")[1]) {
            splitData.push(__char[0][pos].split(" ")[1]);
        } else {
            // __char[0][pos] = "";
            splitData[pos] = " "
        }
        __char[0][pos] = __char[0][pos].trim().split(" ")[0]; //_char[0][pos] _char[0].splice[];
        // _char[0][pos] = splitData[0];
        // _char[0].splice
        // console.log(_char[0][pos].split(" ")[0]); //_char[0][pos] _char[0].splice[];
    }
    console.log(__char)
    __char.splice(1, 0, splitData)
    console.log(__char)

    for (let row = 0; row < __char.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < __char[row].length; col++) {
            let width = this.ctx.measureText(__char[row][col]).width + 3;
            if (!maxRow[0][col + 1]) {
                maxRow[0][col + 1] = 0;
            }
            maxRow[0][col + 1] = maxRow[0][col + 1] < width ? width : maxRow[0][col + 1];
        }
    }
    // console.log(maxRow)

    for (let i = 1; i < maxRow.length; i++) {
        maxRow[0][i] = maxRow[0][i] + maxRow[0][i - 1];

    }


    /* for (let index = 0; index < _char.length; index++) {
        // const element = array[index];
        maxRow[index] = ctx.measureText(_char[index]).width;
    } */
    // _char = __char
    return maxRow;
}

createFonts(start, end) {
    let arr = [];
    // clearEvents();
    for (let index = "/".charCodeAt(0); index <= ":".charCodeAt(0); index++) {
        // const element = array[index];
        // fillCanvas(index);
        let txt = String.fromCharCode(index);
        fillTextCanvas(txt, 0, 0, 1, 0, 32);
        createCanvas(32, this.ctx.measureText(txt).width, 32);
        this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        // fillTextCanvas(txt, text_x, text_y);
        this.clrCanvas();
        fillTextCanvas(txt, 0, 0, 1, 0, 32);
        arr.push(display_hex);
        // fillMatrix();
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    // startEvents();
}

findFirstPositive(b, a, i, c) {
    c = (d, e) => e >= d ? (a = d + (e - d) / 2, 0 < b(a) && (a == d || 0 >= b(a - 1)) ? a : 0 >= 
   b(a) ? c(a + 1, e) : c(d, a - 1)) : -1
    for (i = 1; 0 >= b(i);) i *= 2
    return c(i / 2, i) | 0
}

getDPI() {
    var dpi = findFirstPositive(x => matchMedia(`(max-resolution: ${x}dpi)`).matches);
    return dpi
}

getImage() {
        return this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
    }
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = Canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas does not respect your devices pixel ratio, this is **not** a specific electron issue.

The code you have copy and pasted from another StackOverflow won't work because you change the size/height again without respecting the ratio. If you uncomment it and adjust it correctly, it will work.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I am new in this can you explain it which code segment are you are mentioning above.

and can you help me more in this if i share my complete code.

i want crispy text in canvas to change it into a bitmap and show in led panal like led show software.